# Buscar un número en un vector. Devolver -1 si no se encuentra o devolver la posición donde está si el elemento está en el vector

Tags: c

no sé donde está el error, ponga lo que ponga, siempre me sale "No se ha encontrado ninguno".
Es la función 3 y el case 3.

```
#define nmax 50
        int vect[nmax];

   #include <stdio.h>
#define nmax 50

void leer_vector (int vector[],int num);
void mostrar_vector (int vector[], int num);
int buscar_vector (int vector[], int num, int num_buscar);

    void main () {

        int cont, n, num, i, opcion, res, num_buscar;   
        int vector[nmax];

        n = 1;

        while (n!=0) {
            printf("\nSelecciona una opcio: \n");
            printf("1.- Introduir un vector (NO podrà superar 50 caràcters):\n");
            printf("2.- Mostra el vector per pantalla.\n");
            printf("3.- Buscar un element en el vector.\n");
            printf("4.- Comptar quantes vegades apareix el mateix caràcter en el vector.\n");
            printf("5.- Buscar la posició de l'element més gran del vector.\n");
            printf("6.- Ordena el vector amb el métode de la bombolla.\n");
            printf("0.- Salir del programa.\n");
            scanf("%d", &n);

            switch (n) {

                case 1: 
                    printf("Introduce la longitud del vector: \n");
                    scanf ("%d", &num);

                    printf ("Introduce el vector: \n");
                    leer_vector (vector, num);
                    break;

                case 2: 
                    mostrar_vector (vector, num);
                    break;

                case 3: //No ha acabat de funcionar.
                    printf ("Escriu el número a buscar: ");
                    scanf ("%d", &num_buscar);
                    res = buscar_vector(vector, num_buscar, num);

                    if (res -1){
                        printf ("No s'ha trobat cap.\n");
                    }

                    else {
                        printf ("Es la posició: %d\n", res);
                    }   
                    break;
            }
        }    
    }


    // Función número 1.

    void leer_vector (int vector[],int num) {
        int i;

            for (i = 0; i<num; i++) {
                scanf("%d", &vector[i]);

            }
    }


    // Función número 2.

    void mostrar_vector (int vector[],int num) {
        int i;
            for (i = 0; i<num; i++) {
                printf ("%d ", vector[i]);
            }
    }


    // Función número 3.

    int buscar_vector (int vector[], int num, int num_buscar) {
        int i, cont;
            i = 0;
            cont = 0;
            while ((i < num) && (cont == 0)){
                if (vector[i] == num_buscar){
                    return (i);
                    cont = 1;
                }
                i ++;
            }
        return (-1);
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cambia `if (res - 1)` por `if (res == -1)`.

Comment: Que va, tampoco funciona, me sigue saliendo lo mismo. ¡Gracias por responder!

Comment: Bueno, me refiero a que no funciona correctamente, me devuelve siempre el mismo resultado, es decir "No se ha encontrado ninguno.".

Comment: @NaCl publica la respuesta hombre :-p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gran parte de tu error, es que tu código está mal, específicamente en la llamada a la función `buscar_vector`:

```
printf ("Escriu el número a buscar: ");
scanf ("%d", &num_buscar);
res = buscar_vector(vector, num_buscar, num);

if (res -1) {
    printf ("No s'ha trobat cap.\n");
}
else {
    printf ("Es la posició: %d\n", res);
}   
break;
```

La firma de la función `buscar_vector` exige 3 argumentos: `vector`, `num` y `num_buscar`, sin embargo, al llamar la función, pasas mal los argumentos:

```
res = buscar_vector(vector, num_buscar, num);
```

Cuando debería ser *(De acuerdo a la definición de tu función)*:

```
res = buscar_vector(vector, num, num_buscar);
```

Y terminando por:

```
if (res -1) {
    printf ("No s'ha trobat cap.\n");
}
```

La parte de `res - 1` se evalua a verdadero si `res` es mayor a 1 o igual que cero, debido a que: `0 - 1` es igual a `-1` y `2 - 1` es igual a `1` y, en C, esto es `true` *(Verdadero)*, para solucionarlo, sólo aplica el operador `==` a ambos valores:

```
if (res == -1) {
  // ...
}
```

---

#### Con todas las correcciones aplicadas, tu código queda así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define nmax 50

void leer_vector (int vector[],int num);
void mostrar_vector (int vector[], int num);
int buscar_vector (int vector[], int num, int num_buscar);

int main () {
    int cont, n, num, i, opcion, res, num_buscar;   
    int vector[nmax];
    n = 1;

    while (n!=0) {
        printf("\nSelecciona una opcio: \n");
        printf("1.- Introduir un vector (NO podrà superar 50 caràcters):\n");
        printf("2.- Mostra el vector per pantalla.\n");
        printf("3.- Buscar un element en el vector.\n");
        printf("4.- Comptar quantes vegades apareix el mateix caràcter en el vector.\n");
        printf("5.- Buscar la posició de l'element més gran del vector.\n");
        printf("6.- Ordena el vector amb el métode de la bombolla.\n");
        printf("0.- Salir del programa.\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        switch (n) {
            case 1: 
                printf("Introduce la longitud del vector: \n");
                scanf ("%d", &num);

                printf ("Introduce el vector: \n");
                leer_vector (vector, num);
                break;
            case 2: 
                mostrar_vector (vector, num); break;
            case 3: //No ha acabat de funcionar.
                printf ("Escriu el número a buscar: ");
                scanf ("%d", &num_buscar);
                res = buscar_vector(vector, num, num_buscar);
                if (res == -1)
                    printf ("No s'ha trobat cap.\n");
                else 
                    printf ("Es la posició: %d\n", res);
                break;
        }
    }    
}

void leer_vector(int vector[], int num) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<num; i++) 
        scanf("%d", &vector[i]);
}

void mostrar_vector (int vector[], int num) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<num; i++) 
        printf ("%d ", vector[i]);
}

int buscar_vector (int vector[], int num, int num_buscar) {
    int i, cont;
    i = 0;
    cont = 0;
    while ((i < num) && (cont == 0)){
        if (vector[i] == num_buscar) 
            return (i);
        i++;
    }
    return (-1);
}
```

Me ha funcionado correctamente :), espero que te ayude.

Aquí te dejo un [`repl.it`](https://repl.it/@IamNaCl/RespuestaParaAlex)

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, me has ayudado mucho.
Una última consulta, ¿por qué no abres y cierras los fors?
¡Un saludo!

Comment: Lo de los `for` es una característica de C, te deja poner sólo una sentencia sin necesidad de poner los bloques, lo puse así porque al momento de leer el código, no entendía mucho, así que lo ordené a mi manera, espero no sea un problema, si supone alguno, puedes volverlos a poner sin problema; nótese que no se debe abusar de esta práctica :)

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha ayudado, considera votar positivo y/o aceptar la respuesta utilizando _la palomilla_ a la esquina izquierda de la respuesta :), saludos!